# Question about the Fourier Expansion of $f(ax)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier series transform of a function $f(x)$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{F} [f(x)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-i k x} dx 
$$

Apparently, we also have
$$
\mathcal{F} [f(ax)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax) e^{-i k x} dx 
$$
However, I am unsure of why this would not be expressed as
$$
\mathcal{F} [f(ax)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax) e^{-i k a x} dx 
$$

Can anyone please explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Read your course again.

If $a > 0$ then (change of variable $y = ax$) $$\mathcal{F} [f(ax)](k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax) e^{-i k  x} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) e^{-i k  y/a} \frac{dy}{a} = \frac{1}{a} \mathcal{F} [f(x)](k/a) $$

If $a < 0$ then
$$\mathcal{F} [f(ax)](k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax) e^{-i k  x} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(y) e^{-i k  y/a} \frac{dy}{a} = \frac{1}{|a|} \mathcal{F} [f(x)](k/a) $$

And this last formula $\mathcal{F} [f(ax)](k)=\frac{1}{|a|} \mathcal{F} [f(x)](k/a)$ is true whenever $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$. See also the big [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms).

Answer (score 0):

Just call $g(x) = f(ax)$, then you have

$$
\mathcal{F} [g(x)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) e^{-i k x} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(a x) e^{-i k x} dx = \mathcal{F} [f(ax)]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of the transformation as an operator that takes in a function $f$, and spit out another function $\mathcal F[f]$.

Now you have another function $g(x) = f \circ l(x)$, where $l(x) = ax $

But no matter how complicated your $g(x)$, the operator still treat it as an input and map it to another function the same way.